# My java hibernate code throwing the error "Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]"

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and have downloaded a user registration code as part of learning practice and executed it in my workspace.
Everything looked fine and working at the UI level, but I don't see the record in DB when a user gets registered. Expecting a result when user registration finishes a new record to be inserted into the table which is now not happening.

Need your help/suggestions if any on this issue.

My project Structure:

[image]

My Registration screen:
[image]

Once filled all details and clicked on "Register" button, I get a confirmation shown as below:
[image]

Here comes the problem, when I go and check the table, nothing shows up there and I even don't know if the code has established a DB connection successfully.

My web.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HibernateWebApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>User</display-name>
        <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jwt.hibernate.controller.UserControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Success</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Success</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jwt.hibernate.controller.Success</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Success</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Success</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>register.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: run a select query, see if you get the correct result, or if you get an exception ...

Comment: @Stultuske if you mean to run select query in DB, yes it's a simple select * from table_name and I don't have any issues in running it.

Comment: then how do you not know whether you have a connection to your DB? do you get the results you expect, or do you have "no issues" by hiding the exceptions? without seeing any of your code and knowing what you are doing, it's pretty hard for us to tell

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strangely, I missed to surround my below mentioned code with try catch block and this is where the exception is caught when included my code in try catch.

Solution:  Added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar` to my project and it worked fine.

My Code:

```
  // 1. configuring hibernate
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

            // 2. create sessionfactory
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

            // 3. Get Session object
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            // 4. Starting Transaction
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserName(userName);
            user.setPassword1(password);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setCity(city);
            user.setPhone(phone);
            session.save(user);
            transaction.commit();
```

Thanks!